# Grammatical modification of quote attributed to Appius Claudius Crassus Caecus (340-273 B.C)

Tags: classical-latin

Is this grammatically correct: "Quisque fortunae suae faber est"?

Comment: Could you edit your original question and add the original quote, as well as some additional context for the quote?

Answer (score 3):

The quotation is attributed to Appius Claudius Caecus by the Pseudo-Sallust, *Epistula ad Caesarem senem de republica* 1,1,2: *sed res docuit id verum esse, quod in carminibus Appius ait, fabrum esse suae quemque fortunae*.

The phrase is usually quoted in nominative (*Faber est suae quisque fortunae*): your reworking, which is just a change in the word order, is acceptable.

An interesting parallel is in Plautus. *Trin.* 363 (*ipsus fingit fortunam sibi*), which survives in medieval times: *fortunam sibi quisque parat* (H. Walther, *Proverbia sententiaeque Latinitatis Medii Aevi*, 9898a).

Comment: Thanks very much for your input!  I really appreciate it  My (German) high school Latin (4 years) is 1960's vintage, so it's getting very rusty.  I was merely trying to simplify the syntax by untangling the elegant, but to the uninitiated,, confusing, placement of the subject (quisque) between elements of the object (faber suae fortunae) and further complicating the sentence structure by splitting the genitive indirect object (suae fortunae) with the subject (quisque)..  My sincere thanks again!